# Enable WinRM on a remote machine from a client machine

Tags: powershell, azure

Requirement: Run PowerShell scripts on Remote Server from a Client Machine.

In order to run powershell scripts on a remote computer, we have to use

```
Enter-PSSession
```

In order to do the same, the client and the server must be able to communicate with each other through WinRM service. To achieve the same, we need to enable a firewall port (if not already open), create a new certificate and associate the same port with the thumbprint to enable communication.

I can achieve the same by creating a PS script, and run it on the server.

But if I have to do the same for 40 odd servers, then I need some kind of automation. So, here I am looking for help wherein I can enable communication between two servers, by not manually logging to each and every server but rather through PowerShell to enable WinRM for a server from client machine.

My end goal is to migrate all the existing infrastructure into Cloud and to achieve the same, the only hurdle is communication between to servers.

**Note: I am able to achieve all the need by running a script into the server by manually logging into it and run the script. Post running the script, I am able to get Session of the server in my Client machine.**

Comment: Are your servers Domain joined?

Comment: All the servers are Domain joined but client will be on different domain

Comment: Then I'd use [Group Policy](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2014/05/enable-winrm-via-group-policy/) to enable WinRM.

Answer (score 1):

**Amended**

Looks like your option will be to either use PSTools, which I think will work. Download the set and then use

```
psexec \\[computer name] -u [admin account name] -p [admin account password] -h -d powershell.exe "enable-psremoting -force"
```

Then you can remotely run your script.

OR

You could remotely deploy a scheduled task that points to your .PS1 file.

Comment: Thanks Ross for your reply. But the command which you provided in your answer, it starts the WinRM service of the remote computer. But what I am looking for is to run a script, which will enable WinRM on a remote server. Below is list of steps which needs to be performed: 1) Create Firewall Rule inside the server OS 2) Create Cert 3) Configure WinRM to listen on the port https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/02/11/configuring-winrm-over-https-to-enable-powershell-remoting/

Comment: bear with me, I'll amend the above!

Comment: I do have a script which does all the steps mentioned in the link. But the main issue is how will I be able to run this to a remote machine

Comment: Amended with another attempt at an answer! If this works, let me know and I'll remove the other junk on the answer.

Comment: Hi Ross, the command uses WinRM for RDP, and thus since WinRM is still not set up at the remote machine. It is failing. Motive is to up the WinRM service of the machine. Below is the error which I get : "WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception 
for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers 
within the same local subnet"

Comment: Changed the above answer. Let me know if this helps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139863/discussion-between-partho-ganguly-and-ross-lyons).